On clicking Test Plan in JMeter applicaiton I am getting the error in console
Error in the console :
2024-06-05 16:47:05,530 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory
at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:109) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:184) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.displayPopUp(JMeterTreeListener.java:246) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.mousePressed(JMeterTreeListener.java:188) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:288) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:287) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:287) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:287) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:287) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6623) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4572) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException [in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.separateItemsWithExplicitOrder(MenuFactory.java:246) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.(MenuFactory.java:110) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:109) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:184) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:49) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:83) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117) [?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:191) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:236) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1080) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1728) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1675) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1036) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1016) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.SplashScreen.lambda$showScreen$0(SplashScreen.java:95) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[?:?]
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741) ~[?:?]
... 6 more
I am unable to perform right click actin on Test Plan

Try changing Look and Feel under "Options" main menu entry to something not starting with Darklaf

if you cannot use main menu as well you can run JMeter as:
jmeter -Jjmeter.laf=CrossPlatform

and in order to make the change permanent add the next line to user.properties file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform

More information:

Look and Feel configuration
Configuring JMeter
Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide

